# Is it possible to prove that $\dagger$ is associative?

Tags: set-theory, binary-operations, associativity

Let $\dagger$ be a binary operation acted on two sets. It has the properties
$$\forall A\forall B\forall C \Big(A\dagger B=A\dagger C\iff B=C\Big)$$
and
$$\forall A\forall B\Big(A\dagger B=\Big((A\cap B) \dagger (A\cap B)\Big)\dagger(A\Delta B)\Big)$$

Here, I'm using $\Delta$ to represent the symmetric difference: $A\Delta B=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$

From the second property, we can infer that $\dagger$ is communitive.

> From these properties alone, can we prove that $\dagger$ is associative? I.e; $$\forall A\forall B\forall C \Big((A\dagger B)\dagger C = A\dagger (B\dagger C)\Big)$$

I've tried expanding $(A\dagger B)\dagger C = A\dagger (B\dagger C)$ recursively through property two, but it gets quite messy. I have a hunch that it is associative, but I can't seem to continue.

**Edit:** I hadn't a specific set theory in mind, but in case certain axioms are aren't naively unnecessary, let's assume the realm of **ZFC**.

---

If your curious, I'm afraid it's quite difficult to explain why this came up without boring everyone. But briefly, I've been studying set theories that are highly related to $p$-adic systems, and this operation comes up when defining hyperoperations. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing quantifiers

Comment: @Bananach Good catch. I sometimes forget that lazy notation leads to confusion.